# idk how to read char symbols in file while i will not meet space (Java)

Tags: java, file, numbers, filereader

I have this code

```
char c;
FileReader fr = new FileReader("text.txt");
while(true){
    c = (char)fr.read();
    if (c == ' ')
        break;
    System.out.println(c);
    }
```

but when reader meets a space, he doesn't finishing the work.

Comment: Unable to reproduce!! Created file `text.txt` with content `Hello World` and program printed `H` `e` `l` `l` `o`, then stopped.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem, it was necessary to check the number

```
int c;
FileReader fr = new FileReader("text.txt");
while(true){
    c = fr.read();
    if (c == 32)
        break;
    System.out.println((char)c);
    }
```

Comment: Since `' '` has value `32`, that cannot be it. Your issue was something else. Since the issue can't be reproduced with the original code, it's impossible to say what your original issue actually was.